# Responsive Design - Slider disappears

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on [that theme](http://html5up.net/arcana). My version (as a example) is [here](http://rosafarben.bplaced.net/index.html).

By scaling the browser-window the slider graphic disappears under the navigation. I would like to post some XHTML/CSS, but I do not have an idea where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At line 2886 of your main.css, set the padding-top to 84px like below. Should work.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 840px)
    #page-wrapper {
        ...
        ...
        padding-top: 84px;
        }
```